# java error: constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor

Tags: java, constructor

The following code returns me an error saying: 
`"constructor call must be the first statment in a constructor."`

I dont get it. The constructor in my code is the first statement. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class labelsAndIcons extends JFrame
{
    public labelFrame()
    {
        super( "Testing JLabel" );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The constructors name must be the same as the class name, so change either change the class name to `labelFrame` or the constructor name to `labelsAndIcons`.

Example *(note that usually the first letter is a capital letter in java)*:

```
public class LabelFrame extends JFrame {
    public LabelFrame() {
        super( "Testing JLabel" );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

do you mean

```
public class labelsAndIcons extends JFrame {
    public labelsAndIcons ()
    {
        super( "Testing JLabel" );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructors name must be the same as the class name.
Let's look at this:

```
constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor
```

The constructor word in `constructor call` references the super class's constructor which is the `super();`

The constructor word in `in a constructor` refers to your class's consucor that is : `public labelsAndIcons()`

so you need to narrow your code to this:

```
public class labelsAndIcons extends JFrame
{
  public labelsAndIcons ()
  {
     super( "Testing JLabel" );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally your code should fail saying `Invalid Method declartion` because `public labelFrame()`

- is neither a constructor *(because constructor has the same name as the class name)*.
- is neither proper method declaration.

Whatever change your code like this:

```
public class labelsAndIcons extends JFrame
{
  public labelsAndIcons ()
  {
     super( "Testing JLabel" );
  }
}
```